# Sonar dashobard showing zero values in all widgets

Tags: sonarqube-4.5

If I am adding Sonar in post build action (in Jenkins ) I see all the values as Zero on sonar dashboard widgets but if I provide sonar properties in Jenkins maven goals then I see the correct values on sonar dashboard. I am using sonar 4.5.1 . What is being missed that I see zero values on dashboard while adding Sonar in post build action ?

Comment: May I have a reply on this please ?

Comment: Any reply on my question please ?

Comment: Please answer this question.